# How do you Disable Certain Days on a Datepicker - Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to implement a datepicker but I need to disable some days. For example, I do not want the user to pick Friday and Saturday. I read in other posts that I need to use this [library](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#additional-options), but I still do not know how it works and how to do it in Kotlin. Someone help me plz.

Comment: check https://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/disable-past-dates-in-custom-calendar-view-android ,https://github.com/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View/issues/11 and https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/android/controls/calendar/calendar-disabled-dates that may useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the library documentation there is mentioned that how to use select able days and how to disable certain days. For both purpose you have to pass the array of days to the respective methods.
For example if you want to select certain days only you have to pass the array of days to the  method. To create the days arraylist use following code

```
Calendar[] days = new Calendar[13];
for (int i = -6; i < 7; i++) {
    Calendar day = Calendar.getInstance();
    day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i * 2);
    days[i + 6] = day;
}
```

Now after initializing the datpicker dialog call the method to select the days or disable days.

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(MainActivity.this,
                    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
datePickerDialog.setDisabledDays(days)
```

Comment: datePickerDialog.setDisabledDays is not showing in options.