# How to disable SPECIFIC dates of Material DatePicker on Android studio project?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, concurrency, materialdatepicker

**Background**: I was working on an Android project where concurrencies in date booking will raise, and I have used **MaterialDatePicker** in order to choose the dates.

**Problem**: I need to DISABLE some **SPECIFIC** dates that are already selected by other users in order to handle the concurrencies. I am able to fetch the dates selected by other users from the firestore (Firebase - backend development platform), but unable to deal with the calender. I came across a blog which suggests to use **setDisabledDays(calender[] days)**, but not so clearly how to do that?!

**Need help with!** - how do I disable specific dates on the calender???

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    calendar.clear();
    long today = MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(today);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
    long January = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
    long December = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    CalendarConstraints.Builder calenderConstraintBuilder = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
    calenderConstraintBuilder.setOpenAt(today);
    calenderConstraintBuilder.setValidator(DateValidatorPointForward.now());
    MaterialDatePicker.Builder builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
    builder.setTitleText("Select start date");
    builder.setCalendarConstraints(calenderConstraintBuilder.build());
    MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker = builder.build(); 

    mDatePickerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DATE_PICKER");
        }
    });

    materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPositiveButtonClick(Object selection) {
            duration = materialDatePicker.getHeaderText();
            //This duration variable must be stored in database, it has both start and end date
            dateResult.setText("Selected dates: " + duration);
        }
    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53454711/how-do-you-disable-certain-days-on-a-datepicker-android.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a custom DateValidator when i wanted to block all the dates.

```
public class DateValidatorBlockAll implements CalendarConstraints.DateValidator {
public static final Parcelable.Creator<DateValidatorBlockAll> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<DateValidatorBlockAll>() {
    @Override
    public DateValidatorBlockAll createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
        return new DateValidatorBlockAll();
    }

    @Override
    public DateValidatorBlockAll[] newArray(int size) {
        return new DateValidatorBlockAll[size];
    }
};

public DateValidatorBlockAll() {}

@Override
public boolean isValid(long date) {
    /* 
    Add your logic here
    
    if date == the dates you want to block 
        return false
    else 
        return true
      */
    
    
    return false;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}}
```

And then replace this line of code

```
calenderConstraintBuilder.setValidator(DateValidatorPointForward.now());
```

with

```
calenderConstraintBuilder.setValidator(new DateValidatorBlockAll());
```